# how to calculate a minutes from the TimeStamp in java?

Tags: java

I want to calculate the number of minutes from the TimeStamp. How to do that? for exmple

I have a TimeStamp value as 13/11/10 1:01 PM. I need to get that in minutes since the current time?

Hope I am clear
THanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the value is in `String`.

1. Parse that string using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)'s [`parse()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) method
2. get the time in long from your [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object using [`getTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29)
3. Take a difference of `System.currentTimeMillis()` and the long received from `getTime()`
4. Divide that by 1000 and then 60

Assuming the value is in [`Timestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), skip step 1 and 2. And notice **s** in Time**s**tamp is in lowercase.

Answer (score 15):

`Timestamp` is a `java.util.Date` with a bit more precision - so assuming you don't care too much about the nanos, just call `getTime()` on it to get the millis since the epoch:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis(); // See note below
long then = timestamp.getTime();

// Positive if 'now' is later than 'then',
// negative if 'then' is later than 'now'
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now - then);
```

Note that for testability, I personally *wouldn't* use `System.currentTimeMillis` - I'd have an interface (e.g. `Clock`) representing a "current time service", and inject that. You can then easily have a fake clock.

EDIT: I've assumed you've already got a parsed value. If you haven't, and only have a string, you'll need to parse it first. I'd personally recommend [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) as a rather better date and time API than the built-in stuff, unless you have a particular reason not to use it.

Comment: i tried 
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(then - now);
but it gives value in minus i changed it into
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(  now - then);

Comment: @KhizarHayat: Yes, that would be correct if `now` is later than `then`.

Comment: Timestamp is in `java.sql.Timestamp` for me... Why not use `getMinutes()` even though it's deprecated instead of implementing this on our own though?

Comment: @shinzou: How would you use `getMinutes()` to get the minutes between the current time and the timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Timestamp.getTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime()) to get the time in milliseconds. [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) will give you the same thing for the current time. Subtract them and divide by `1000*60` to convert the milliseconds to minutes